# Concatenating two text columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, string-concatenation

My data looks like this:

```
round <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))
experiment <- rep(c("V1", "V2", "V3"), 2)
results <- rnorm(mean = 10, n = 6)

df <- data.frame(round, experiment, results)

> df
  round experiment   results
1     A         V1  9.782025
2     A         V2  8.973996
3     A         V3  9.271109
4     B         V1  9.374961
5     B         V2  8.313307
6     B         V3 10.837787
```

I have a different dataset that will be merged with this one where each combo of `round` and `experiment` is a unique row value, ie, `"A_V1"`. So what I really want is a variable `name` that concatenates the two columns together. However, this is tougher to do in dplyr than I expected. I tried:

```
name_mix <- paste0(df$round, "_", df$experiment)
new_df <- df %>%
  mutate(name = name_mix) %>%
  select(name, results)
```

But I got the error, `Column name must be length 1 (the group size), not 6`. I also tried the simple base-R approach of `cbind(df, name_mix)` but received a similar error telling me that `df` and `name_mix` were of different sizes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `new_df <- df %>% mutate(name=paste0(round, "_", experiment))`. Though if i copy/paste your code i cannot reproduce that error. Are you sure there's no typo somewhere?

Comment: @MrFlick I don't get an error message at all, so a little confused... Maybe update `dplyr`?

Comment: checked my code (from IRL, not the example above) like crazy for typos, so I don't think it's that. Using `unite`, as below, seems to work.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the `unite` function from `tidyr`

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  unite(round_experiment, c("round", "experiment"))

  round_experiment   results
1             A_V1  8.797624
2             A_V2  9.721078
3             A_V3 10.519000
4             B_V1  9.714066
5             B_V2  9.952211
6             B_V3  9.642900
```

Answer (score 13):

This should do the trick if you are looking for a new variable

```
library(tidyverse)

round <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))
experiment <- rep(c("V1", "V2", "V3"), 2)
results <- rnorm(mean = 10, n = 6)

df <- data.frame(round, experiment, results)
df

df <- df %>% mutate(
  name = paste(round, experiment, sep = "_")
)
```

Comment: Either this, or the `unite` suggestion, could have been the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You could also try this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% 
   unite(combined, round, experiment, sep = "_", remove = FALSE)
```

The output will be:

```
combined round experiment   results
 A_V1     A         V1      10.152329
 A_V2     A         V2      10.863128
 A_V3     A         V3      10.975773
 B_V1     B         V1       9.964696
 B_V2     B         V2       9.876675
 B_V3     B         V3       9.252936
```

This will retain your original columns.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be to use the stri_join function in stringi package.

```
library(stringi)
df$new = stri_join(df$round,df$experiment,sep="_")
```